# Javascript, Wrapper & Content made heading disappear on My server http://localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

The Sidebar, Feed, and Widgets from the heading suddenly disappeared from local host when I added the wrapper and content, where did it go?

Here is my code:

```
 import { constants } from 'buffer'
    import type { NextPage } from 'next'
    import Head from 'next/head'
    import Image from 'next/image'

   const style = {
  wrapper: 'flex justify-center h-screen w-screen select-none bg [#1520b] text-white',
  content: 'max-w-[1400px] w-2/3 flex justify between',
}

export default function Home(){
  return (
  <div className = {style.wrapper}>
    <div className = {style.content}>
      <h2>Sidebar</h2>
      <h2>Feed</h2>
      <h2>Widgets</h2>
   </div>  
   </div>  
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's going on:
you add the `text-white` to the `wrapper` so all text is white and the default background color is white too so the page will look like it's empty.

also the `bg [#1520b]` the value here is invalid it should be 3 or 6 letters long and you should connect it with `bg` using `-` like this `bg-[#1520b9]`, but it won't work either because you can't use arbitrary values in tailwind with react like this.
so I would recommend that you move it to inline style like this:

`style={{backgroundColor:'#1520bf'}}`

and the same goes for `max-w-[1400px]` make it :

`style={{maxWidth:'1400px'}}`

So your code should look like this:

```
    import { constants } from 'buffer'
    import type { NextPage } from 'next'
    import Head from 'next/head'
    import Image from 'next/image'

    const style = {
          wrapper: 'flex justify-center h-screen w-screen select-none  text-white',
          content: ' w-2/3 flex justify-between',
         }


export default function Home(){
  return (
  <div className = {style.wrapper} style={{backgroundColor:'#1520bf'}}>
    <div className = {style.content} style={{maxWidth:'1400px'}}>
      <h2>Sidebar</h2>
      <h2>Feed</h2>
      <h2>Widgets</h2>
   </div>  
   </div>  
  )
}
```